# React js fail to move component to next row when screen gets smaller using @media

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to make a detail product page with two components- one image component on the left and one product Info component on the right with full computer screen. I want the whole product info component (it includes product title, description and price) move to the next row below the image when the screen gets smaller or when using phone to view that page. I try to use @media as the code shown below, but it fails to do the change I want. the two components still stay in the same row and the image become too small to see when the screen gets smaller

In DetailProductPage.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import ProductImages from './ProductImages';
import ProductInfo from './ProductInfo';
import {productItems} from '../Data';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import './DetailProductPage.css';

function DetailProductPage() {

    const { id }=useParams();
    const [details, setDetails]=useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails(productItems.find(item => String(item.id) ===id ))
    
     }, [id]);
        
    return (
      <div className="detailInfo" style={{width:'100%', padding: '3rem 4rem'}}>
          <div className="detailLeft">
               <ProductImages detail={details} />
           </div>
          
           <div className="detailRight">
               <ProductInfo  detail={details} />
           </div> 
      </div>
  )
}


export default DetailProductPage
```

In DetailProductPage.css

```
.detailInfo{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  max-width: 1500px;
  background-color: white;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
  .detailLeft {
    flex:2;
    max-width: 850px;
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: 30x;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  
  .detailRight{
    flex:1;
    width: 40%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    
  }

  @media (max-width: 100px){
    .detailInfo{
     display: block;    
    }
```

Comment: trying making the `max-width` in your media query bigger to something like 750px (the width of iphone 6)

Comment: Yes, It works when I change the max-width to 750px. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When I change the max-width to 750px as WebbH's comment, it works.